# Unable to delete Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net

I am trying to clear `Temporary ASP.Net files` folder using following command

> rmdir /q /s "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

But I am getting acces denied error even after iis is stopped. How can I delete/clear the folder?

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a permissions issue and not that the files are locked by a process then these steps should work.

From an administrative command prompt run these commands.

- takeown /f *.* /r /d y
- icacls *.* /grant administrators:F /t
- del *.* /f /q
- rd /s /q

For more details see my the post on my blog:
http://mythoughtsonit.com/2013/03/how-to-delete-those-pesky-undeletable-files/